# Are there any good books on spherical geometry?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

Lately I've been interested in learning spherical geometry; however, when I google for book recommendations, there are not many, and the few there are don't actually say the name of any book. The weird thing is that if I look for hyperbolic geometry, there are many recommendations. why is this? is hyperbolic more popular than spherical?

Also, I don't know if spherical geometry is a long-enough topic to write an entire book on it, since the best recommendations I've seen so far, are book chapters.

So do you know any good books on the aforementioned subject?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any book of Riemannian Geometry is worth

Comment: http://math.rice.edu/~pcmi/sphere/ is on-line link to spherical geometry notes from Rice University.

Answer (score 8):

Try Van Brummelen's book entitled *Heavenly Mathematics*: https://press.princeton.edu/titles/9834.html

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in spherical trigonometry, one free resource is an old (1886) textbook, "Spherical Trigonometry; For the Use of Colleges and Schools" by I. Todhunter, available from Project Gutenberg: [Spherical Trigonometry](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/19770).